# Node.js issues with exporting functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have a few questions about the nature of exporting functions in NodeJS:

Firstly this is an acceptable way to export a function:

```
exports.bread = function bread() {
  return 'bread: 2';
};
```

However, it is not possible (maybe?) to export a function using this method:

```
function pullData(pair) {
  console.log(pair);
}

module.exports = pullData;
```

The only problem with this second method is that the function is not hoisted and limits its' use elsewhere?

Another method for exporting variables is to include the variables within an object and export that object. However, in this case, the functions within the module have a limited scope...

So is there any easy way to export declarative functions and use them, or is doing so not something I should strive to achieve?

Screenshots from project:
[image: Main file code and console output]

[image: Code from the exporting file]

Comment: You'd have to do `tradeData('TEST');`. Or rewrite the module to `module.exports = { pullData: pullData };`

Comment: _The only problem with this second method is that the function is not hoisted_ Yes it is, it's not hoisted in the first method however.

Comment: Yeah sorry George, I meant it the other way round :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `module.exports = something` you are exporting only one thing. So your code should look like this

```
var pullData = require('./getTicker')
pullData('TEST')
```

If you want to write it the way you have done so then you need to export it differently, as only part of the `module.exports` object.
You can do this by writing
`exports.pullData = pullData` in your `getTicker` file.

Then you can import it and use it like you did:

```
var trackData = require('./getTicker')
trackData.pullData('TEST')
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Not only helped my do it my way, but also showed me a few cool techniques :)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting pullData in curly brackets:

```
module.exports = {pullData}
```

and when you require it, do this:

```
const {pullData} = require("./getTicker");
```

Hope it'll work.